# Get all checkins from last few hours/day(s)/week(s)

Tags: tfs-sdk

I would like to have a list of the check ins of a teamproject from the last hours, day(s), week(s), .... Is this possible through the TFS SDK (programmatically!!)? How can I do this?

From this information, I would like to make some statistics like the project activity, based on the number of checkins of the last day for example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. Maybe someone can use it:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamCol = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverURL));
        VersionControlServer vcs = tfsTeamCol.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        var history = vcs.QueryHistory("$/*", // The local path to an item for which history will be queried. This parameter can include wildcards
                                         VersionSpec.Latest, //Search latest version
                                         0, //No unique deletion id
                                         RecursionType.Full, //Full recursion on the path
                                         null, //All users
                                         new DateVersionSpec(DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(7)), //From the 7 days ago ... 
                                         LatestVersionSpec.Instance, //To the current version ...
                                         Int32.MaxValue, //Include all changes. Can limit the number you get back.
                                         false, //Don't include details of items, only metadata. 
                                         false //Slot mode is false. 
                                        );

int changesetCounter = 0;
        foreach (Changeset changeset in history)
        {
            changesetCounter++;
         //...
        }
```

If there is a better solution, please let me know !